# How do I convert an array list to hash separated string?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am new to c# and I am using String.Join to attempt to turn an array list into a string that is hash separated, such as "1#2#3#4". I can't seem to get the syntax working correctly.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
ArrayList aryTest = new ArrayList();
aryTest.Add("1");
aryTest.Add("2");
aryTest.Add("3");
string strTest = "";
strTest = string.Join("#", aryTest.ToArray(typeof(string)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var joined = string.Join("#", list);
```

An `ArrayList` is an "old" generation class, that does not implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface that is needed for `string.Join`, and also is not an `string[]` or `object[]` array, which could be used in a call to `string.Join`.

You are better of using a `List<string>`, because then you will not have to do `ToArray`, to allocate a new array, just to create a string.

Comment: OP does not use `ArrayList` directly. Instead, he calls `ToArray`. One of `ToArray` can be cast to `string[]`, another implements `IEnumerable`. (A agree that ArrayList is not strongly typed, and `List<string>` looks as a better choice.)

Answer (score 3):

You need an extra cast:

```
strTest = string.Join("#", (string[])aryTest.ToArray(typeof(string)));
```

Alternatively, use just `ToArray()`, without any arguments:

```
strTest = string.Join("#", aryTest.ToArray());
```

The reason is that different overloads of `Join` are called:

```
strTest.ToArray(typeof(string))           ---> string.Join(string, params object[])
    // ToArray(Type) returns Array, it is passed as _one object_,
    // its ToString() is called, the results is "System.String[]"

(string[])strTest.ToArray(typeof(string)) ---> string.Join(string, params string[])

strTest.ToArray()                         ---> string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)
    // ToArray() returns object[]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Foreach loop in arrays too;

```
ArrayList aryTest = new ArrayList();
aryTest.Add("1");
aryTest.Add("2");
aryTest.Add("3");
string strTest = "";
foreach (var a in aryTest)
{
strTest += a +"#";
}
strTest.TrimEnd(new char[] {'#'});
```

Comment: This will add a trailing hash-symbol in the final string. Like `1#2#3#`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use aggregate queries and get the same result. If you are interested in using LINQ or you want your code to look more nicer and clean.

```
 ArrayList aryTest = new ArrayList();
            aryTest.Add("1");
            aryTest.Add("2");
            aryTest.Add("3");
            string strTest = "";            
 strTest = aryTest.ToArray().Aggregate((current, next) => current + "#" + next).ToString();
```

The output would be:

```
1#2#3
```

An aggregate is a function that takes a collection of values and returns a scalar value. Examples from T-SQL include min, max, and sum. C# supports aggregates and aggregates as extension methods. Using the dot-notation you can simply call a method on an IEnumerable object.

**Note to keep in mind: As I am not using StringBuilder it will have negative performance for very long sequences. But for short sequences it will just fine.**